# How to make Scatterplot using Tuples

Tags: python

Having issues with my code below. Trying to create a scatterplot from tuples:

```
#Convert CSV file to dictionary to store data
reader = csv.reader(open('winemag-data-130k-v2.csv'))
number = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    number[key] = row[1:]

#Convert dictionary data to tuples
t = list(number.items())

#Make scatter plot from tuples
# create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# scatter the points against the price
ax.scatter(t['[points]'], t['price'])
# set a title and labels
ax.set_title('Wines')
ax.set_xlabel('points')
ax.set_ylabel('price')
```

I keep on getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in the  ax.scatter line.

t looks like this when you print it:
...
('6257',
['US',
'Toasty oak and black pepper hit first on the palate and nose, followed by '
'savory, dry tannin, black cherry and vanilla. Restrained and in balance, '
'the Cabernet is supported by 12% Petit Verdot, which adds girth and '
'intensity without becoming extreme.',
'',
'90',
'60.0',
'California',
'Mount Veeder',
'Napa',
'Virginie Boone',
'@vboone',
'Renteria 2012 Cabernet Sauvignon (Mount Veeder)',
'Cabernet Sauvignon',
'Renteria']),
...

I'm trying to access that '90' and the '60.0'. Any ideas?

Comment: what does your csv data look like?  also why not use pandas?

Comment: also in your ax.scatter, check where quotes are.  it should probably be `t['points']` and not `t'[points]'`.

Comment: updated the post to show what t looks like

Comment: i don't understand.  is this a row?  what are the headings?

Comment: try `df = pd.read_csv('winemag-data-130k-v2.csv')`  and then share the first few rows how they look.  `df.head()`.  (you will need to `import pandas as pd`).

Comment: read_csv has an encoding type, use iso  https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings